# Inserting generated UUID into table - can't adapt type UUID

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I'm populating a table like so:

```
...
time_id = uuid.uuid4()
location_id = uuid.uuid4()
id = row['id']

sql = '''
        INSERT INTO "my-schema"."example"(
            ...
            time_id,
            location_id
            id
        ) VALUES (..., %s, %s, %s)
'''
data = (..., time_id, location_id, id)
try:
    my_cursor.execute(sql, data)
    my_conn.commit()
except (psycopg2.Error) as e:
    print(e)
```

With the following table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE "my-schema".example
(
  ...
  time_id character varying(50),
  location_id character varying(50),
  CONSTRAINT "PK_example" PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE "my-schema".example
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

However this gives me the following error: `can't adapt type 'UUID'`. What would the reason for this be? I need the `time_id` and `location_id` to be unique as they act as a foreign key between a dimension and fact table.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the UUID data type to store UUIDs? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-uuid.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

uuid is a particular type which looks like a string, but isn't. You're trying to put it into a character field. You need to convert it to a string first: `str(time_id), str(location_id)`.

Comment: Perfect, will accept answer when time constraint is up.

Comment: There is a better way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59268003/10650942