# How to debug a connection or cursor objects?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm facing a odd problem where `result = cursor.fetchone()` return None when there is data in the DB.

please let me explain why is odd, I created a single connection

```
connection = psycopg2.connect(
            user=environ["DB_USER"],
            password=environ["DB_PASS"],
            host=environ["DB_HOST"],
            port=environ["DB_PORT"],
            database=environ["DB_NAME"],
        )
```

then I pass that connection to a function, this function creates a cursor, does some queries, closes the cursor and return the result. At this point the connections works, the cursor works. Then I pass the same connection to another function and this is where I have the problem:

```
def check_dependency(connection, uuid):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    tablename = environ["PIPILE_NAME"]

    sql_str = f"SELECT * FROM {tablename} "
    sql_str += "WHERE uuid = %s "
    sql_str += "AND NOT decrypt_status;"

    cursor.execute(sql_str, (uuid,))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    cursor.close()
    print(sql_str, uuid, result)  #<-- this output
    return result
```

I copied the output, ran it in postgresql directly and it returned the row that I was expected but the function returns None.

I believe the problem might be in the connection or the cursor, but I don't know how to make sure they are ok

Comment: Probably this may help: [psycopg2: Can't adapt type 'UUID'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51105100/1995738)

Answer (score 0):

You are unsure whether the connection is still working properly.
To debug this, create a connection and then
immediately call the `check_dependency` function twice.
If the 2nd call fails we may be able to blame it on the connection,
but if the 1st call fails then you'll want to revise the function.